# Links floating to the left?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Many of the links on my site are ignoring css rules and floating to the left. It's just the links, the other text seems fine. You can see here, https://adsler.co.uk/dating/ under terms and conditions on mobile view, or in the Privacy Policy page, `between you and Adsler.co.uk. By registering, you are agreeing that we will process you data in accordance with our Privacy Policy, 
Terms and Conditions 
and
Cookie Policy` https://adsler.co.uk/privacy-policy/

Aside from them being very naughty links :-) what's causing this and how to rectify?

I have this html from `f12` which is the only thing i could identify as potential cause. Unable to supply css because not sure what's causing it?

```
<div class= "entry-content" >
<p> Text <p>
<p dir="ltr">
Text...
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In future, instead of linking to a separate site, please create a [mcve] demonstrating the problem and include that in the question.  (The problem with external links is that when you fix this error on your site this question will become useless for future users.)

Comment: (That said, the bug here is that you've set `a {display: block}`, which is causing those links to be block elements instead of inline.)

Comment: Thanks but if i unset `a {display: block;} ` then it will unset all the `a's` that I want `display: block;}`....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have defined the `display:block;` property on the `anchor` tag.

You need to change the `anchor` property to `display:inline-block;` or you can 
override the `anchor` property with class inherit.

```
.entry-content a
{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

[image: Solution]

[image: Screenshot]

I hope it will work for you!

Comment: Thanks but will that also display any `a'S` that I want `display: block` to  display `inline-block`, under that div class?

Comment: @One89 if you need specific element style `block`. You can apply the class on the specific element.